# Negating INT_MIN in CPP

Tags: c++, integer, minimum

The question I am trying to solve is:

> Implement `pow(x, n)`, which calculates `x` raised to the power `n` (Leetcode problem 50)

I have the following code:

```
class Solution {
 public:
  double myPow(double x, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
      cout << "in last";
      return 1;
    } else if (n < 0) {
      x = 1 / x;

      return myPow(x, -n);
    } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
      double y;
      cout << "in even";
      y = myPow(x, n / 2);
      cout << "y is ";
      cout << y;
      return (y * y);

    }

    else {
      cout << "in odd";
      double j = myPow(x, n - 1);
      cout << "j is ";
      cout << x * j;
      return (x * j);
    }
  }
};
```

When ran for the test case `x=1.00000` and `n = -2147483648`. I am getting the error:

```
runtime error: negation of -2147483648 cannot be represented in type 'int'; cast to an unsigned type to negate this value to itself (solution.cpp)
```

Why do I get this and how shall I solve it? TIA

Comment: With a typical 2's complement signed integer type, the negative of the minimum value cannot be represented in the type's positive range.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to support `-2147483648` then you need to use a `long long` type, not an `int`.

If `int` is a 32 bit 2's complement type then `2147483648` is actually a `long` or a `long long` type.

There are no such things as negative literals in C++ (`-2147483648` is a compile time evaluable constant expression consisting of the negation of the literal `2147483648`), so `-2147483648` is either a `long` or a `long long` type too. This is why you'll often see `INT_MIN` defined as `-2147483647 - 1`.

If the above is the case on your platform then the behaviour of your code is *undefined* for that input, as you are overflowing an `int` type.

Answer (score -1):

- A 4 bytes (or 32 bits) `int` has a range of **-2,147,483,648** to **2,147,483,647**, thus if you negate **-2,147,483,648** you can't represent it as `int`.
- You could try using `unsigned int` (which has a range of
  0 to 4,294,967,295) or `long long int` (which a range of -(2^63) to (2^63)-1) make this negation and fit the positive value there.

I opted for a different approach and handled this case separately since it is the only value that will cause us trouble.

- Add 1 to that negative value before negating it.
- To compensate for that I multiplicate the base once more separately.

```cs
if (n == -2,147,483,648)
{
    return (1.0/x) * myPow(1.0/x, -(n + 1));
}
```

The full solution

```cs
double myPow(double x, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1.0;

    if (n < 0)
    {
        if (n == -2,147,483,648)
        {
            return (1.0/x) * myPow(1.0/x, -(n + 1));
        }

        return myPow(1.0/x, -n);
        }
        
    return (n % 2 == 0) ? myPow(x * x, n / 2) : x * myPow(x * x, n / 2);
}
```